# Color swatches in filter layered navigation

Tags: product, filter, configurable-swatches

In Filter by Color, I have 3 colors red, brown and blue displaying in filter layered but I need to show them as red, blue and brown square boxes.

How to display it?

Please suggest a solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-use-color-swatches-in-layered-navigation.html

This link will be helpful....

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the configurable swatches from  **System > Configuration > Configurable Swatches**. Then add the swatch images to the color attribute and enable it for layered navigation.

By default the rwd theme supports showing swatch images in the layered navigation.Otherwise you need to make the changes in the layered navigation phtml file.